keycloak after upgrading cannot access admin console with domain
version upgrading from 10.0.2 to 24.0.3;
I use rancher to deploy keycloak.
In old vesrion, configed environment：KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL"https://passporttest.example.com/auth" and nginx resolves domain  to ip
In new vesion, I search Alternatives instead of environmentKEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL is directly set frontend URL in realm settings. And in my business realms, it worked successfully.
The problem is in master realm, after same way  I do in set frontend URL in master realm settings,
I cant open admin console through "https://passporttest.example.com/auth/admin/master/console.
btw, I build an image with keycloak24.0.3 in dev-mode
here is my dockefile
`FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.3
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh", "start-dev"]`
here is my rancher pod environment:
environment
How can I solve it?  much thanks

Well I hava solved it . Add a new environment: KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN_URL ,  and set master realm frontend url with same url env used. The solution source is from https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14666
